# Why do we need to divide the loss in case of multi-dimensional labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following TensorFlow's tutorial on [custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#define_the_loss_function).
There are two things that I do not understand:

First, when defining the losses, the authors point to dividing by the shape of one example, in the case of a multi-dimensional labels:

"If `labels` is multi-dimensional, then average the `per_example_loss` across the number of elements in each sample. For example, if the shape of predictions is `(batch_size, H, W, n_classes)` and labels is `(batch_size, H, W)`, you will need to update per_example_loss like: `per_example_loss /= tf.cast(tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(labels)[1:]), tf.float32)`"

Why do we need to rescale the loss this way?

Secondly, a general question: I noticed that several functions use the `with strategy.scope()` annotation. If this object is available globally, then we can define a function on the global level like this

```
with strategy.scope():
  def example_function():
    #do stuff
```

If the object is not available globally, we have to structure the code like this:

```
def train():
  strategy = ...

  with strategy.scope():
    def sub_function1():
      #do stuff
```

This leads to one large function, `train()`, with many short sub functions. I'd like to define the sub functions on the same level as `train()`, without using a global `strategy` object.
Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further users, this question was answered [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48586).